# Can i import my primary key in Neo4j with CSV

Tags: neo4j, cypher, load-csv

I'm importing CSV files to Neo4J, but Neo4J doesn't import my primary key.

I'm using this:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///C:/c/tabela_sujeito.csv" AS row
CREATE(:Sujeito{suj_ID:row.id, idade:row.idade, altura:row.altura, peso:row.peso, genero:row.genero, mao_dominante:row.mao_dominante});
```

`suj_ID` is my primary key, and it isn't imported, unlike the other attributes.

Comment: Can you share the first few of the records along with header? It's difficult to say something without seeing your file.

Comment: **There is no concept of `primary key` in Neo4j**. You can add a unique constraint on a property if required.

Comment: I know that in neo4j there isn't primary key. The records are like: "3,27,173,69,masculino,direita
4,25,175,90,masculino,direita"

Comment: "3" and "4" are the PK. And i need to import that, but only imports the other attributes

Comment: Can you share the header?

Comment: Yes. "suj_ID,idade,altura,peso,genero,mao_dominante" suj_ID it's the PK

Comment: In that case you need to use `row.suj_ID`, and not `row.id` as you currently have in your CREATE.

Comment: Thanks @InverseFalcon that's correct

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by **@InverseFalcon**, You need to use `row.suj_ID` instead of `row.id`  in your query.

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///C:/c/tabela_sujeito.csv" AS row
CREATE(:Sujeito{suj_ID:row.suj_ID, idade:row.idade, altura:row.altura, peso:row.peso, genero:row.genero, mao_dominante:row.mao_dominante});
```

Comment: Other question, did you know how can i increase dbms.memory.heap.max_size in neo4j desktop?

Comment: Separate questions belong in separate questions :-)